# Facebook Comments not working in Wordpress

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm using Facebook Comments plugin, I contacted the developer of the plugin and he is saying it's a Facebook app issue. I made sure my application ids matched, but I'm still having the issue. See it here: http://kimpercivalblog.com at the bottom of the posts.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is not working is not specific enough. I just went to your website and comments are working as far as I see. Although there is some message: warning... Edit: facebook says: `The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http://www.kimpercivalblog.com/my-church-dallas-fort-worth-family-photograph/.` So you have to change it to match your domain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup fb application and config plugin with your app key. Here http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/installation/ is info how.

Here is screenshot: paste key in first input box as in picture.

[image: Fb comments plugin settings]

And just a friendly advice, use built in WordPress comments, believe me they work so much better. Fb comments - been there, done that, it just ain't worth it. They are buggy and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are working - but you can see there is an error - in the yellow box below it. My client is requesting the FB comments be installed.

I tried both of those things - I checked the domain settings in my facebook app - it is correct.

I checked the application Id - it is correct and I inputed it into the first box of the plugin.

I even tried CSS to "hide" the box and it did not work!

Any other ideas?? :(

Comment: Check the domain settings in the FB App again, this time with a *really* strong eye. The presence or lack of "www" matters. The capitalization matters. Basically, your Site URL should be "http:/ /www.kimpercivalblog.com/" and nothing else whatsoever will work.